# blackjack python code player cannot stand on a value of 15 or less

Tags: python

im trying to implement a while loop that if the current card value is 15 or less the player cannot 'stand', they must 'hit', therefore the input choice appears again. 
but when the code is run i get the print statement below displayed countless times.

```
play = input('| Please enter h or s (h = Hit, s = Stand:) ')
while play == 's' and totalplayer <= 15:
print('Cannot stand on value less then 15')
```

above is the current code i have. Is their a piece of code missing that is causing the print statement to be displayed countless times?

Comment: If you start a loop using comparisons whose logical value is not changed within the loop you get an infinite loop. Also check the rules of blackjack. There are different 'can stand' values for dealer and player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing your indentation:

```
play = input('| Please enter h or s (h = Hit, s = Stand:) ')
while play == 's' and totalplayer <= 15:
    print('Cannot stand on value less then 15')
```

`while` loops keep executing continuously while the loop conditions are true.  There is no code inside your loop body that would change any of the conditions, so they always remain true and the loop executes forever.

Try putting another copy of the input statement inside the while loop, so the player has a chance to change his answer.

Changing the `while` to an `if` might also work, depending on how the surrounding code is organized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have much more code written than you provided above, but there isn't anything in the code that allows it to exit the loop. While loops continue to do whatever you instruct them to do until a condition is met that has it stop. While `play == s` and `totalplayer <= 15`, it's going to print the statement. But after the statement is printed, it goes back to check if the while condition is still true. The play is still s and the number of plays is still less than 15 because nothing has changed them, so it prints it again. It will keep doing this forever because it has no further instructions than that.

In addition to printing the statement, you also need it to run the play function to get input again. Depending on how the rest of the code is set up, you could also consider using an if statement instead, which would only `print('Cannot stand on value less then 15')` once if the condition is true, then stop and move on.

Comment: how would i allow the user to input again?

Comment: Call the function again or ask for input again. Is that your entire code block? Because you'll need a lot more for a full game! In pseudo code, you'll essentially want to ask for input first. If they enter h, print the number and add it to totalplayer. You'll then ask for the input again. If they enter s, check if totalplayer is less than or equal to 15. If it is, print the statement and ask for the input again. If it isn't, play is over. This is why I think `if` would actually work better.